# Not finding relative modules on build when linked over "npm link xyz"

Tags: npm, webpack, vuejs2, node-modules, symlink

When running `npm run serve`, my VueJS projekt (Vue 2.6.11) running webpack is not finding my locally changed node module.
If i install it normally, it works (of course) and i see the changes i made in it, in the node modules folder of the project that linked it - so the link itself should be fine.

I linked it by using "`npm link`" in the project i want to link (i ran the build before) and then using "`npm link [name]`" in my main project.

The import i'm using in the **main.js** looks like this:

```
import [module-name] from '[module-name]'
```

just as it did when i had it installed regularly.

I also changed the settings of webpack by doing this:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      symlinks: false //npm link
    },
    ...
```

because the documentation of vue stated (for version 2, the new version has information about chainWebpack in it), that links won't work otherwhise as they're not resolved without it. still, this is the output on `npm run serve`:

```
This dependency was not found:

* [module-name] in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/CommentWriteArea.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save [module-name]
```

(with the correct name in it of course)

Other solutions like installing the local version or forking the repository are not an option. It has to be linked for my use case

Comment: Are you using npm v`7`? If so, see this GitHub issue: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2339

Comment: i'm on npm v6.14.6